# php class names , what's the difference

Tags: php, oop, class

I am a new in terms of PHP OOP programming, i don't understand when and how the following class names are and when shall i use them :

```
$a = new Classname();
$a = new Classname;

$a = ClassName::function();
$a = ClassName::getInstance();
```

Many thanks and sorry for silly question:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are identical.

```
$a = new Classname();
$a = new Classname;
```

You can use them interchangeably when the class constructor does not take, or does not require other parameters.

Example:

```
class Classname
{
    public function __construct($var = null)
    {
        // ..
    }

    static public function getInstance()
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

In this case you can use `$a = new Classname;` and `$var` will take the default value, or `$a = new Classname('hello')` and `$var` will be equal to the value passed.

---

These are both [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method calls.

```
$a = ClassName::function();
$a = ClassName::getInstance();
```

One calls a method called "function" (which cannot exist - it is a reserved word), the other calls a method named "getInstance". When you use them really depends on what the methods do.

Static methods can be called without creating an object instance.

I.e.

```
Classname::staticMethod();
```

versus

```
$obj = new Classname;
$obj->method;
```

Comment: @thecatontheflat: Meh, I was editing while they were voting. Always happens ;)

Answer (score 4):

As for

```
$a = new Classname(); 
$a = new Classname;
```

No difference if `__construct()` has no arguments to receive.

---

As for

```
$a = ClassName::function();
$a = ClassName::getInstance();
```

this is just normal call of static methods

Comment: thanks , fair enough , but can I  use  ClassName::function() even if method is not static ? or this is strictly to define static methods ?

Comment: It's strictly *how you call* static methods. You cannot call non-static methods in that manner. You probably need to do some reading about what `static` actually means, and what it is used for.

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
$a = new Classname();
$a = new Classname;
```

These are just 2 different ways of saying the same thing: Create a new reference to class "Classname" without any parameters (php is more lenient in regards to if () and parameters must be given or not than many other programming languages).

For:

```
$a = ClassName::function();
$a = ClassName::getInstance();
```

These two are static calls of the functions "function()" and "getInstance()", thus $a would be set to the appropriate return value of these function. Static means that you can use the
functions without referening the class itself (thus $b=ClassName(); $a=$b->function() is not needed instead you can just write it as you did above).